# How can I solve Navigator.push() error in old version Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hmm... I can't understand why my project have error... Please hlep me.

[Error Message]

```
Error: The getter 'user' isn't defined for the class '_CreatePageState'.
- '_CreatePageState' is from 'package:insta_clone2_start/create_page.dart'('lib/create_page.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'user'.
  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => HomePage(user)),
                                                           ^^^^
```

[Environment]
**NON null_safety

```
environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

[HomePage Code]

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 final FirebaseUser user;

 HomePage(this.user);
```

[Create Page1]

```
class CreatePage extends StatefulWidget {
final FirebaseUser user;
CreatePage(this.user);

@override
_CreatePageState createState() => _CreatePageState();
   }
```

[Create Page2]

```
  Navigator.push(
  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => HomePage(user)),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```html
  Navigator.push(
  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => HomePage(widget.user)),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  FirebaseUser e=FirebaseUser();//create object from class FirebaseUser
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
     
      home:Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(
  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => HomePage(user:e)),//see the difference
);

        }),
      ));
  }
}
```